# get the value of onclick element a and use it in a websql query

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, web-sql

I want to alert a string inside the query of a websql or use the string inside the websql

```
var db = openDatabase('asean', '1.0', 'my first database', 20 * 1024 * 1024);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".lvl_link").click(function () {
    var lvl_numbers = $(this).attr("lvl_number");
    alert(lvl_numbers+"a");

        db.transaction(function (tx) {
           tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM lvlTABLE', [], function (tx, results) {
            alert(lvl_numbers);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing preventing you to use variable inside WebSQL callbacks. But the function you are passing as 3rd argument to `executeSql` is a success callback, it might be that your method has failed and that's why you can't see the alert.

Try adding failure callback like this:

```
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
       tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM lvlTABLE', [], function (tx, results) {
        alert(lvl_numbers);
       }, function(tx, error) {
           alert(lvl_numbers + '/error: ' + error.message)});
    });
```

You'll find more details about `executeSql` in the [WebSQL specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#executing-sql-statements). People don't like reading specifications, but for WebSQL there is not much other documentation.

Comment: I am blogging all of my progress as I go, because there is so little info out there... but you are right, the success and error handlers are vital to troubleshoot this type of issue.